# RoR Print HTML Page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I need to make one of my views printable on a A4 page. Could you please suggest an easy way to so it ? Are there any Ruby gems that take care of that. Or will I need to work with CSS? :(

Thanks

Comment: I am sorry, your question is not so clear.. so do you want to print the html view ?

Comment: Yes. But make sure that things like the wallpapers, are not included ewtc etc

Comment: You need to use css. Take a look at http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

You have to go on
Javascript Print() method :)